# Failed to send mail with SSL=true on port 25 using javax.mail

Tags: email, smtp

// Below is my configuration:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); 
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 

Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                         return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
                      }
                     };

 Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);
```

//My port number is 25 and SSL should be true. I am getting below exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1090)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:986)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
```

Comment: Are you sure this hosts accepts SSL on port 25? Is it also listening on 587? This may be a server that supports Opportunistic SSL via STARTTLS in which case the chat starts plaintext and then can be elevated to TLS. Also, check the JavaMail docs. You can debug at the transport level which will give you all the SSL chat details.

Comment: We have simple test application in VB6.0 to send mail.  In VB  test application with port 25 & SSL true it sends email successfully.

Comment: Then you need to debug the transport using the instructions from JavaMail.